# DROPBOX API Not uploading more than 150MB File

Tags: php, curl, dropbox-api

Hi Please first read full question then answer.
I am trying to upload the files using `Dropbox API` But now I came to know that I cannot upload more than 150MB file with that method.
Here are my Codes.

```
<?php 
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$filename = SITE_ROOT.'BRINDABELLA.zip';

$MainPath = '/2020 events/';

$api_url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.
    json_encode(
        array(
            "path"=> $MainPath.basename($filename),
            "mode" => "add",
            "autorename" => true,
            "mute" => false
        )
    )

);

$ch = curl_init($api_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$path = $filename;
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
$filesize = filesize($path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo($response.'<br/>');
echo($http_code.'<br/>');

curl_close($ch);    
?>
```

I Know I can upload more than 150MB files using `upload session` method.
Reference Link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload_session-start

Now I just want to alter my these codes only. Please help me how I can do it. I dont want to use any external API. Just the way I used `CURL`

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected? Where are you stuck? Do you get any error message(s) when implementing 'Upload sessions' as described in the documentation?

Comment: @berend Yes. When i upload a file more than 150MB it gives 413 Error Code. 
I explored the Dropbox for that code. It belongs to the Bigger files than 150MB. Whereas, The less files are going Perfect.. No issue for the Smaller files <150MB